# Round off time value to before midnight in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, case

I am writing a query that will allow me to workout dates for when particular jobs need to be completed.

The following is a list of my jobs and codes.

```
JOB_NO | CODES | RCVD_TIME
ABC1 | 1 | 07-JAN-17 09:44:07 
DEF2 | 3 | 20-MAR-17 14:32:49
GHI3 | 3 | 27-MAR-17 10:00:03
JKL4 | 1 | 12-JAN-17 12:59:05
```

Now I have a few conditions in order to workout the end date/time for these jobs.

Code 1 - Add 1 day + anytime until 23:59:59
Code 3 - If rcvd time is before 1pm then job to be completed same day until 23:59:59, if rcvd time is 1pm or after then job to be completed before 1pm next day.

My simple query:

```
SELECT 
JOB_NO, CODES, RCVD_TIME,
CASE
  WHEN CODES = '1'
  THEN RCVD_TIME + 1
ELSE RCVD_TIME
END AS TARGET
FROM...
```

This gives me (not sure how to write query for codes 3):

```
JOB_NO | CODES | RCVD_TIME | TARGET
ABC1 | 1 | 07-JAN-17 09:44:07 | 08-JAN-17 09:44:07
DEF2 | 3 | 20-MAR-17 14:32:49 | 20-MAR-17 14:32:49 
GHI3 | 3 | 27-MAR-17 10:00:03 | 27-MAR-17 10:00:03
JKL4 | 1 | 12-JAN-17 12:59:05 | 13-JAN-17 12:59:05
```

This is what I would like:

```
JOB_NO | CODES | RCVD_TIME | TARGET
ABC1 | 1 | 07-JAN-17 09:44:07 | 08-JAN-17 23:59:59
DEF2 | 3 | 20-MAR-17 14:32:49 | 21-MAR-17 13:00:00 
GHI3 | 3 | 27-MAR-17 10:00:03 | 27-MAR-17 23:59:59
JKL4 | 1 | 12-JAN-17 12:59:05 | 13-JAN-17 23:59:59
```

Would really appreciate if somebody could advise on how I can get my required answer.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT

bit frustrating but been told to add one more condition to consider working day of the week is between 1 and 6 so have to make sure the target time does not fall into a sunday (day 7). sorry guys for the double, just thought I would add it here in case it gets missed.

Comment: Just to be sure, `RCVD_TIME` column is of datatype `date` right, not `varchar`?

Comment: that's right its a date datatype

Comment: Are 1 and 3 the only possible values of `CODES`? If other values are possible, how is `TARGET` calculated?

Comment: mathguy, the other possibility was 2 but this only requires an addition of 6 hours.

Comment: "Addition of 6 hours" meaning exactly 6 hours after the `rcvd_time`? Then, regarding Sundays: for `CODES = 2`, if you have to skip Sundays, this means if a request comes in at 22:00 on a Saturday, the `target` becomes 04:00 the following Monday? That must be handled also. Then: Is it possible that the `rcvd_time` itself is on a Sunday? In that case, how do the requirements change? (For example, if something comes in before 1 pm and has code 3, and it's on a Sunday... is it due by the end of day on Monday? or by 1 pm? What if it comes in at 4 pm on a Sunday?)

Comment: thanks mathguy, given it a bit more thought, codes 1, 2 if they come in on a Saturday, then this needs to have a target date for Monday and if codes 1 and 2 have a job on a sunday then this falls into Monday again. if a job with code 3 comes in before 1pm on a sunday then this needs to complete by midnight on the sunday, whereas if a job with code 3 comes after 1pm on sunday then this needs a target date of the Monday by 1pm. Code 4 would work on days 1-7 just adding 6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` statement in your SQL to handle your complex if-then logic.

```
-- TEST_DATA is not part of the solution
with test_data ( job_no, code, rcvd_time, target ) AS (
SELECT 'ABC1',1,to_date('07-JAN-17 09:44:07','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('08-JAN-17 09:44:07','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'DEF2',3,to_date('20-MAR-17 14:32:49','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('20-MAR-17 14:32:49','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'GHI3',3,to_date('27-MAR-17 10:00:03','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('27-MAR-17 10:00:03','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'JKL4',1,to_date('12-JAN-17 12:59:05','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('13-JAN-17 12:59:05','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL)
-- Actual solution begins here...
SELECT job_no, code, rcvd_time,
       case
           when rcvd_time - trunc(rcvd_time) < 13/24 and code = 1 then
              trunc(rcvd_time) + (86399/86400) + 1 
           when rcvd_time - trunc(rcvd_time) < 13/24 and code = 3 then
              trunc(rcvd_time) + (86399/86400)
           when rcvd_time - trunc(rcvd_time) >= 13/24  then
              trunc(rcvd_time) + 1 + (13/24)
       end target
from test_data;
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the prompt responses. Will give them a go and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interval literals (so you do not need to sprinkle magic numbers throughout your code):

```
CASE
  WHEN code = 1
  THEN TRUNC( rcvd_time ) + INTERVAL '2' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
  WHEN code = 3 AND TO_CHAR( rcvd_time, 'HH24' ) < '13'
  THEN TRUNC( rcvd_time ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
  WHEN code = 3 -- AND TO_CHAR( rcvd_time, 'HH24' ) >= '13'
  THEN TRUNC( rcvd_time ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '13' HOUR
END
```

To compare the time you can use various different techniques:

- `TO_CHAR( rcvd_time, 'HH24' ) < '13'`
- `EXTRACT( HOUR FROM CAST( rcvd_time AS TIMESTAMP ) ) < 13`
- `rcvd_time < TRUNC( rcvd_time ) + INTERVAL '13' HOUR`

Answer (score 0):

In the solution below, I assume that the "special" handling applies only when `CODES` is 3, otherwise the `TARGET` is the end of the next day. (This allows `CODES` values other than 1 and 3... you can adapt if you have more `CODES` values and additional rules.)

Since all `TARGET` date-times are offset from `trunc(rcvd_time)`, I use a `CASE` expression just to determine the offset.

```
select job_no, codes, rcvd_time,
       trunc(rcvd_time) +
         case codes when 3 then 
                         case when extract (hour from cast (rcvd_time as timestamp)) < 13 
                                          then interval '23:59:59' hour to second
                               else interval '1 13:00:00' day to second
                               end
                    else interval '1 23:59:59' day to second
                    end  as target
from   your_table;
```

NOTE:  Thanks to MT0 for showing the ways to extract hour from a date; I had forgotten that `extract(hour from...)` works only for timestamps. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: ok, bit frustrating but been told to add one more condition to consider working day of the week is between 1 and 6 so have to make sure the target time does not fall into a sunday (day 7).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
t.*
,case when codes=3 
        and to_date(to_char(rcvd_time,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')
                    >=to_date('13:00:00','HH24:MI:SS')      
    then trunc(rcvd_time)+1+(13/24) -- add 1 day and then add 13 hours
when codes=1 
    then trunc(rcvd_time)+2-(1/(24*60*60)) --add 2 days and subtract 1 second
 else 
    trunc(rcvd_time)+1-(1/(24*60*60)) -- add 1 day and subtract 1 second
 end as target
from tbl t;
```

Working sample

```
with tbl (JOB_NO,CODES,RCVD_TIME) as (
select 'ABC1',1,to_date('07-JAN-17 09:44:07','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
select 'DEF2',3,to_date('20-MAR-17 14:32:49','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
select 'GHI3',3,to_date('27-MAR-17 10:00:03','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
select 'JKL4',1,to_date('12-JAN-17 12:59:05','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') from dual)
select 
t.*
,case when codes=3 
        and to_date(to_char(rcvd_time,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')
                    >=to_date('13:00:00','HH24:MI:SS')      
    then trunc(rcvd_time)+1+(13/24) -- add 1 day and then add 13 hours
when codes=1 
    then trunc(rcvd_time)+2-(1/(24*60*60)) --add 2 days and subtract 1 second
 else 
    trunc(rcvd_timeJOB_NO,CODES,RCVD_TIME)+1-(1/(24*60*60)) -- add 1 day and subtract 1 second
 end as target
from tbl t;
```

Output

```
JOB_NO  CODES   RCVD_TIME               TARGET          
ABC1    1   07-JAN-2017 09:44:07    08-JAN-2017 23:59:59
DEF2    3   20-MAR-2017 14:32:49    21-MAR-2017 13:00:00
GHI3    3   27-MAR-2017 10:00:03    27-MAR-2017 23:59:59
JKL4    1   12-JAN-2017 12:59:05    13-JAN-2017 23:59:59
```